# PHP not printing current URL

Tags: php

I am starting to build my own MVC using PHP and I am trying to get the current URL in order to create a routing system. I am following a video and the code is as follows. However, it isn't working.

```
<?php
// phpinfo();
echo "15";
$url = $_GET['url'];
// echo $url;
```

Comment: `$_GET['url']` is not the variable you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for `$_GET['url']`

`$_GET['URL']` is a **get** statment ..  Meaning you need to pass a variable through the URL IE `http://example.com?URL=myurl`

To get the current URL .. Simply use `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` will get you the get parameters, not the entire url. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for that.